# Plotly figure has no attribute "full_figure_for_development"

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am having trouble using plotly Figure's "full_figure_for_development" in python, it raises an AttributeError.

**Code:**

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
full_figure = fig.full_figure_for_development()
```

**I get:**

```py
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'full_figure_for_development'
```

Is there any workaround / specific version of plotly I should use ?

**Environment:**

- Python 3.7.6 on linux
- Plotly 4.6.0
- kaleido 0.2.1

Thanks !

Comment: Currently, the latest version is 4.14.3, so it may improve with an upgrade.
I tried this page in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/figure-introspection/#more-about-layout) in my environment, and it was output correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is version-related, you need at least version 4.10 because that is when this feature was released. According to version [4.10 release notes](https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-py-4-10-date-axis-improvements-a-faster-px-imshow-and-full-figures-for-development/44685) you can see that they mention the `full_figure_for_development` as a new feature for that version.

> The new fig.full_figure_for_development() function will return a new go.Figure object, prepopulated with the same values you provided, as well as all the default values computed by Plotly.js, to allow you to learn more about what attributes control every detail of your figure and how you can customize them. This function is named “for development” because it’s not necessary to use it to produce figures, but it can be really handy to explore figures while you’re figuring out how to build them. Check out our new figure introspection documentation 16 for more details and examples